# XSLT - remove value and add attribute

Tags: xml, xslt

When a node has the attribute `class="deleted"`, I want to add the value of a node into an attribute called `text`.

This input:

```
<element class="deleted" >
    <span>Example</span>
</element>
```

Should create this output:

```
<element class="deleted" text="&ltspan>Example&lt/span>" /> **Edit**
```

The .xsl I use is:

```
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="node()[@class = 'deleted']">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:attribute name="text">
            <xsl:value-of select="child::node()" />
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

and the output is not as wanted it is like:

```
<element text="Example" class="deleted"><span>Example</span></element>
```

The problem is I don't know how to remove the value and get the `span`tags into the attribute `text`

Comment: Are you aware that the output you want is not possible? However you could possibly have <element class="deleted" text="&lt;span>Example&lt;/span>" />

Comment: @kumesana did not think about that, but this output would be also ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the value:

Just don't apply templates after on the value you've copied, but only on the attributes.

```
<xsl:template match="node()[@class = 'deleted']">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
        <xsl:attribute name="text">
            <xsl:value-of select="child::node()" />
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

To put the value with its tags inside the attribute, you pretty much need to serialize it to text. You could define a template in charge of that:

```
<xsl:template mode="serialize-to-text" match="text()">
    <xsl:copy/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template mode="serialize-to-text" match="*">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('&lt;', name(), '>')"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates mode="serialize-to-text" select="node()" />
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('&lt;/', name(), '>')"/>
</xsl:template>
```

and call it like that:

```
<xsl:template match="node()[@class = 'deleted']">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:attribute name="text">
            <xsl:apply-templates mode="serialize-to-text" select="node()" />
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: There is only one little problem, `<xsl:copy>` does not copy attributes, so the attribute `class="deleted"` would be lost and my template should not remove any attributes only add the `<text>` attribute. (it is possible a `element` has 0-n attributes and I don't know wich it really has there)